# Create HTML table from associative array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I want to create a table from PHP Associative Array

This is my code:

```
$itemspecifics = array(
    "Condition" => "New",
    "Year" => "2007",
    "Manufacturer" => "Audi",
    "Model" => "A4",
    "Type" => "Limousine",
    "Options" => "Full"
);
```

I want a table to be generated but in this format:

```
<table width="779" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="104">Condition</td>
    <td width="318">New</td>
    <td width="176">Year</td>
    <td width="171">2007</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Manufacturer</td>
    <td>Audi</td>
    <td>Model</td>
    <td>A4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>Limousine</td>
    <td>Options</td>
    <td>Full</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: We will not work for your homework

Answer (score 0):

From that associative array, you must get the keys and value and flatten them inside another array, then chunk them by four's. Consider this example:

On PHP:

```
$itemspecifics = array(
    "Condition" => "New",
    "Year" => "2007",
    "Manufacturer" => "Audi",
    "Model" => "A4",
    "Type" => "Limousine",
    "Options" => "Full"
);

$data = array();
foreach($itemspecifics as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = $key;
    $data[] = $value;
}

$data = array_chunk($data, 4); // chunk them by four's
```

On HTML/PHP:

```
<style>
.header{
    background-color: green;
}
</style>

<!-- them loop them -->
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<?php foreach($data as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach($value as $index => $element): ?>
        <td class="<?php echo ($index % 2 == 0) ? 'header' : ''; ?>"> <!-- simple coloring -->
            <?php echo $element; ?>
        </td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```